# Elasticsearch order responses and then facet

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to order responses by a certain field and then apply faceting? My app contains workorder documents and activity log entries. Employees log time spent working on a workorder by creating activity log entries in separate documents that are then associated with the workorder document. I'd like to be able to query ES and have it return activity log entries ordered by workorderID and then compute a stats facet against the activity log entries for each workorder.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to show exactly for each work order? Can you provide an example?

Comment: AFAIK facets members are not impacted by any search oder?!

Comment: Or you'd like to order, than limit on the sorted results, and than facet?

Comment: I created a gist at https://gist.github.com/fourlincoln10/5581046 that shows the document structure. Basically I have a workorder JSON document and an arbitrary number of activity log entry documents that are related to a workorder through a workorderId property. The log entry docs have a numeric numHours property I want to facet on, but I need to facet per workorder. Ideally, I'd like to get a list of all the log entry docs in the system grouped by workorderId and calculate a stats facet for the numHours property for each group.

Comment: I want the facet to tell me the minimum number of hours spent on a workorder (not activity log entry), the max, mean, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather (glanced at the gist) you don't need info from Workorder-docs to fullfill this query right? i.e: all data you need exists in Activity-docs.

If I understand your question correctly you can use Terms-Stats-field
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-stats-facet/

Whereby you specify:

- `key_field` = workorderId
- `value_field` = numHours

From that url:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag_price_stats" : {
            "terms_stats" : {
                "key_field" : "tag",
                "value_field" : "price"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hth

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm trying to get a stats facet across an activity log entry 'group'. A 'group' is all of the activity log entry documents that are related to a workorder via a workorderId property set in the activity log entry document. I know I could send a query for each workorder, but there could be a couple hundred workorders I need to retrieve at a time so I'm trying to find a way around sending that many queries.

Comment: using `key_field=workorderid` you provide the termfacet with the means  to 'group'  activitylog-docs per workerorderid. The result: one facet for each distinct workorderid will be returned, containing stats (min, max, mean, etc.) taken over the `numhours` field. In short: I believe this does what you say it should in the comments. Note: the termsstat-facet I'm mentioning here is something different than the termsfacet or the statsfacet.

Comment: of course you can limit the actual returned facets to the workorders you need if you don't need all, by a query or a facetfilter

Comment: Yes! this does exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks for your help. The terms facet gives me stats per workorder. The icing on the cake would be if I could go one step further and compute stats for all of the workorders. In other words, now that I have stats per workorder, compute the avg, min and max across the workorders. Do you know if there is a way to do that? It would be pretty easy to loop through the data set and find the min of all of the min values, max of all the  max values, etc. but it would be great if ES could do it for me.

Comment: Great! In this 'aggregate' case, how would avg be calculated? 2 options: 1. does every group of 'activitylogs per workorderid' count as 1? So aggregate avg. would be a normal avg over the averages of all workorder-groups? or 2. a weighted avg (taking nr of activitylogs per group into account) . If 2. this simplifies to simply taking the avg of all activitylogs independent of workerorderid. Simplest would be to have an extra field and let all activiylogs have the same value for that field, which you def a statsfacet on. This spits out min/max as well. In case of avg for 1. you need to loop imo.

Comment: Each group of 'activitylogs per workorderid' would be a group, and I'd like to calculate stats across all of the groups. For example, workorder A has two activitylogs with stats and workorder B has two activitylogs with stats, and I'd like to compute stats that show the min,max and avg for the two groups. It seems like a nested facet would work, but Googling that shows nested facets are slated for version 1.0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30021/discussion-between-geert-jan-and-troy)